# Closing an open boundary in an image

Tags: python, opencv

I have written this algorithm. Its main idea is to close an open boundary in  a binary/grayscale image. However, I got these errors, and I don't know why they appear. I would like to draw a boundary that encloses an open contour around the input point.

The main idea in this algorithm is that it emits rays in the surrounding 360 degrees around the point and estimates the distance between every point it encounters on the boundary and the input image.

[image]
   This is what the result expected to be
[image]

```
 import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from shapely.geometry import polygon,point
    import math
    import statistics

def dot(out,point,raduis,color=128):
    x= point[0]
    y= point[1]
    if raduis == 0:
        out[x,y]=color
    else:
        im = out.shape[0]
        jm = out.shape[1]
        i1 = (x + raduis)
        i2 = (x - raduis)
        j1 = (y + raduis)
        j2 = (y - raduis)
        i1 = i1 if i1 > 0 else 0
        i2 = i2 if i2 > 0 else 0
        j1 = j1 if j1 > 0 else 0
        j2 = j2 if j2 > 0 else 0

        i1 = i1 if i1 < im else im
        i2 = i2 if i2 < im else im
        j1 = j1 if j1 < jm else jm
        j2 = j2 if j2 < jm else jm
        out[i1:i2,j1:j2] = color
#=============================================================
def sin(ang):
    return math.sin(math.radians(ang))
def ray(img,point,ang):
    di = math.sin(math.radians(ang))
    dj = math.cos(math.radians(ang))
    c = 0
    i = point[0]
    j = point[1]
    im = img.shape[0]
    jm = img.shape[1]
    while(1):
        i = round(point[0]+c*di)
        j = round(point[1]+c*dj)
        c+=1
        if 0 > i or i >= im or 0 > j or j >= jm:
            return [*point,0]
        if img[i,j] == 255:
            print((i,j))
            cv2.line(img,point,(i,j),200)
            return [i,j,1]
#---------------------------------------------------------
def raypoly(img,point):
    rr=[]
    for a in range(0,360,10):
        r = ray(img,point,a)
        if r[2] == 1:
            rr.append([r[0],r[1]])
    return rr
#----------------------------------------------------------
def distance(a,b):
    return ((b[0]-a[0])**2+(b[1]-a[1])**2)**0.5
def metrics(point,poly):
    sz = len(poly)
    dav = 0
    dmin = 999999999
    dmax = -1
    dv =[]
    for p in range(sz):
        d = distance(point,poly[p])
        dv.append(d)
        if dmin > d:
            dmin = d
        if dmax < d:
            dmax = d
    return [statistics.mean(dv),statistics.median(dv),dmin,dmax]
#=================================================================
def projectpoint(point,angle,d):
    return [round(point[0]+d*math.cos(math.radians(angle))),round(point[1]+d*math.sin(math.radians(angle)))]
def raypolylimit(img,point,stats):
    u =[]
    med = stats[1]
    mn = stats[2]
    dmin = mn
    do = dmin
    dmax = med +(med-mn)
    sv =[]
    for a in range(0,360,10):
        r = ray(img,point,a)
        q = [r[0],r[1]]
        if r[2] == 1:
            d = distance(point,q)
            if d >= dmin and d >= dmax:
                do = d
                u.append([r[0],r[1]])
                sv.append(d)
            elif d > dmax:
                d = do
                sv.append(d)
                t = projectpoint(point,a,d)
                u.append(t)
            elif d < dmin:
                d = dmin
        else:
            d = do
            sv.append(d)
            t = projectpoint(point,a,d)
            u.append(t)
    return u
#=======================================================
def plotline(a,b,img,color=255):
    di = (a[0]-b[0])
    dj = (a[1]-b[1])
    for k in range(0,500,1):
        i=round(a[0]+di*k/500)
        j=round(a[1]+dj*k/500)
        dot(img,(i,j),0,color)
    return
#--------------------------------------------------------
def plotpoly(poly,img):
    sz =len(poly)
    for i in range(0,sz-1,1):
        p = poly[i]
        q = poly[i+1]
        plotline(p,q,img)
    p = poly[sz-1]
    q = poly[0]
    plotline(p,q,img)
#=======================================================
print(distance((4,4),(7,8)))
img = cv2.imread('imj.jpg')
cv2.imwrite('image.jpg',img)
imo = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imo,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
# cv2.imshow('frame',imo)
# cv2.waitKey(0)
p = (100,100)
poly = raypoly(thresh,p)
stats = metrics(p,poly)
polyc =raypolylimit(thresh,p,stats)
plotpoly(polyc,thresh)
print('Distances for the boundaries = ',polyc)
print('number of points = ',len(poly))
for p in poly:
    dot(img,p,0,color=150)
h ,w =img.shape[:2]
m= 0
for x in range(h):
    for y in range(w):
        if np.all(img[x, y] == 150, axis=-1):  # (img[x, y]==150).all(axis=-1)
        # count = np.count_nonzero((img == [150, 150, 150]).all(axis=2))
            m = m + 1
print('No. of points in original image =' ,m)
plt.subplot(1,2,1),plt.imshow(img)
plt.subplot(1,2,2),plt.imshow(thresh)
plt.show()
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
(25, 163)
  File "D:/My work/MASTERS WORK/FUNCTIONS.py", line 140, in <module>
    plotpoly(polyc,thresh)
(100, 211)
(119, 205)
(136, 199)
  File "D:/My work/MASTERS WORK/FUNCTIONS.py", line 124, in plotpoly
(165, 177)
    plotline(p,q,img)
  File "D:/My work/MASTERS WORK/FUNCTIONS.py", line 116, in plotline
(178, 145)
    dot(img,(i,j),0,color)
(190, 116)
  File "D:/My work/MASTERS WORK/FUNCTIONS.py", line 12, in dot
(180, 86)
    out[x,y]=color
(170, 74)
IndexError: index 226 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 226
```

Comment: That looks like a very common index out of bounds error. You're doing `out[x,y] = color`, but `x` is too big. You should check which values you pass as `point` to the `dot()` function.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli  I have already add the command line (print((x,y))  to stand for the coordinates of the point which has an error and it was (104,226) but when the y value increases , it gives the error but also the second error , I don't know why it gives error in plotline and plot poly functions !

Comment: You'll probably get a better answer if you add a second diagram with the expected result. You may just be looking for the convex hull...

Comment: @MarkSetchell  This is the result that I expect to be